# PowerMock for SecurityContextHolder not working

Tags: spring, spring-security, mockito, powermockito

For the following logic to retrieve name out of SecurityContextHolder was not able to find out solution to get Mock Test completed.

```
String userName = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication().getName();
```

Mock Test :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandlerTest.class)
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandlerTest {

private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        successHandler = new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

    // https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-mvc-test-examples/blob/master/security-url-based/src/test/java/net/petrikainulainen/spring/testmvc/security/util/SecurityContextUtilTest.java

    @Test
    public void test() {

         HttpServletRequest mockRequest = PowerMockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
         HttpServletResponse mockResponse = PowerMockito.mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SecurityContextHolder.class);
        SecurityContext mockSecurityContext = PowerMockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);
        Authentication authenticationMock = PowerMockito.mock(Authentication.class);
        PowerMockito.when(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()).thenReturn(mockSecurityContext);
        PowerMockito.when(mockSecurityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authenticationMock);
        PowerMockito.when(authenticationMock.getName()).thenReturn("userName");
```

...

Maven Dependencies Made sure the

```
<!-- Mock Objects Library for Java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

AND

```
<powermock.version>1.6.2</powermock.version>
```

Are compatible.. but still the response is not correct.

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Answer (score 0):

I see your code and have the feeling that there is something in the `mockStatic` for the `SecurityContextHolder.class`.

Edit: I also see that you use `PrepareForTest(YourTestClass)` but I do not see why you would do this. The `@PrepareForTest` statement is only used for classes (not objects!), so you need to change them before they're instantiated. E.g. You would want to `PrepareForTest` your `SecurityContextHolder.class` class when you are changing the behaviour of some code for all instances of that class (the statics for example...)

You could try this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SecurityContextHolder.class)
public testClass{         
    @Test
    public void testSomething(){
        // this prepares the class; all static methods get a default return value (in this case type Object is returned and the default returned object is null)
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SecurityContextHolder.class, new Answer<Object>() 
        {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return null;
            }
        });

        //Now the class is prepared, we can just change the behaviour of the static method in the way we would like.
        String in = "example input string";
        String out = "example output string";        

        PowerMockito.when(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()).thenReturn(out);
    }
    //..body
}
```